# ko is not defined with requirejs

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I'm trying to use requirejs to load knockoutjs in following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug'], function() {
        var someModel = {
            firstname: ko.observable('asd')
        };
        ko.applyBindings(someModel);
    });
</script>
```

Where require.js is loaded using a Script Tag on top.
When this code executes, I get a ko is not defined error. What's the correct way to do similar?

Comment: how about `function(ko) { .....`

Comment: Thanks HungryCoder.. It resolves the issue. Unforunately I can't mark a comment as an answer but it is.

Comment: Just curious -  what is the logic underneath? If I include 4 libraries in require, I'll have to add 4 parameters to use them? Also, if I just include 2 script tags on page - one for requirejs and other for knockoutjs (in same order and no other code on page), it throws error. Is it that by merely adding requirejs, it conflicts with other following script tags?
My problem is resolved but great if anyone can clear my confusion.

Comment: glad to know it helped. i've made an answer with little more clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require(['scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug'], function(ko) {
```

I'm not sure but seeing the example on requirejs, I guess these are loaded inside the scope of that callback function. So, unless you accept that in your function, you can't use it.

Yes, you are right (at least, seeing their exmaple). if you include 4 libraries, you need to accept 4 parameters. for example, if you loaded jquery and knockout, you can write it as follows:

```
require(['scripts/jquery.js', 'scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug'], function($, ko) {
```